# Guide to Autocomplete as you type (in the box and as suggestions) search with php, mysql and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

I am struggling to use typeahead / bloodhound combined with `ajax` to use `post`, so I thought I would go in another direction, follow a more from scratch route. Unfortunately half of the time the autocomplete people say is just the list of suggestions, the exact type of search I want is as you type it puts into the text field the most appropriate one, rather than just a suggestion below the search.

I eventually want to have something so when you type it would look up the database for the alias too and pick the right one as well as autocompleting it,

i.e. someone types in ms, it brings up *Microsoft* with below it alias: ms, m$ and the likes.

For reference, this is the type of autocomplete I mean:

[See autocomplete mode on the page](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxCombo/)

Unfortunately the above seems to not be free, so I've avoided that one.

[See the basics](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/)

Comment: Is this what you are thinking about? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330543/typeahead-input-field-and-query-passed-to-php-with-ajax

Comment: not quite, i think that is talking about 2 fields, I am talking about using that for a more complicated lookup on the database,e.g. MS would be the same as Microsoft and pull up that result as the right one, I am struggling on even the most basic of sending ajax through typeahead/bloodhound right now though